# How to display the whole number instead of exponential number format

Tags: csv, xls

Can someone tell me how to convince a CSV file saved with the string “88888887039546656102802″ to not turn into an exponential number "8.88888870395466E+22" ? when i load the CSV and reads the exponential number "8.88888870395466E+22" instead of the actual value “88888887039546656102802″.

And after which limit csv convert number into exponential format

how can i avoid this?

Thanks!

Comment: There is nothing the actual CSV format to specify display options.  What software are you using?  Microsoft Excel?

Answer (score 0):

On excel you may choose input method as text by
right click column Select FormatCells
select text format.